# Spring Boot - Let Hibernate initialize all datasources of AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, dynamic, schema

I've implemented the *AbstractRoutingDataSource* in order to horizontally partition my data [1]. I rely on Hibernates functionality to create and update the database schema. This works fine for the first datasource, which is resolved by the *determineCurrentLookupKey()* declared in *AbstractRoutingDataSource*.

Is there a way to apply the schema generation/update to the other datasources as well?

I've found the classes *SchemaExport* and *SchemaUpdate* respectively, that are capable of the required functionality. However, both require an instance of *org.hibernate.boot.MetaData*, which I don't how to obtain.

(I'm using Spring Boot in version 1.4.2.RELEASE.)

[1] https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found a solution using the SchemaExport class of hibernate.
For each DataSourceEnum you can manually initialize the datasource.

[here is my detailed answer to my own issue discription](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304146/5629762)